# Keep Xcode targets up to date

Tags: ios, xcode, project, diff, target

I have an Xcode project with two targets, one for my release version and one for beta testing. The only *intentional* differences between the two targets are Bundle name and Id, so that beta testers can have both release and beta versions installed at once without conflicts and confusion (I'm also thinking about using different icons).

I'm having trouble keeping the two targets up-to-date; for example, when I add a new library to one target, I sometimes forget to click the checkbox to add it to the other target.

Is there an easy way to *automatically* (more or less) keep the two targets synchronized in respect to settings like source code and library contents? Perhaps there's a tool that can do a basic diff of the settings (they seem to be in one main file, so a traditional file diff tool won't help).  Or is there perhaps a better way of maintaining settings for a beta version like I described above?

(I'm using Xcode 4.5.2 for jailbroken iOS development--so I don't need to worry about any App store issues.)

Comment: Depends on how you add the library. More details?

Comment: Usually with drag-and-drop, but the library adding is just one example. I also recently change the header and framework search paths in one target. Would be nice to get this easily (i.e. non-manually) added to the other target.

Comment: Now I see. You really use separate targets. If the only difference is Bundle name and ID, you rather should use one target and add another scheme to that target. You then can set those properties on the scheme level.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know these settings can be set on the scheme level. I'll have to look this up and try it out. If it works (and nothing else comes up), I'll accept this as an answer.

Comment: Tip: Set your Bundle Identifier to `$(BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` in the target summary and add a user defined build setting called `BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` depending on the scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm also changing two other bundle variables (display name and version), all of which are defined in the respective Info.plist files. Do you think it would be possible to specify which Info.plist to use in the pre-action script for the schemes? Maybe I should post another question for this, or if you would post an answer, I'll +1 it so you'll get rewarded for your help ;)

Comment: Perhaps inherit the common settings from the project? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html

Comment: @Dogweather: thanks for the tip, unfortunately AFAIK project settings don't contain information about what sources should be compiled or which objects should be linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I ended up just deleting the target for the beta version and making a copy of the target for the release version (I was too lazy to pursue @ilmiac's helpful suggestions from the question comments). Since the important settings (Bundle name and Id) are stored in the Info.plist file, I just need to change the location of the Info.plist file after copying. To keep the changes to a minimum, I'll settle for having the app being named '*AppName* copy' (the default name Xcode gives to duplicated targets) instead of '*AppName* beta' (the same going for the bundle directory name).